# Off-Canvas Menu: Problems with multilevel menu

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I´ve implemented the Foundation **Off-Canvas Menu as a Multilevel Menu**. When I use the original code example from the documentation, I´ve the problem, that the **submenu isn´t working**. It´s shown but it´s not formated (sub-levels not hidden) and the click event to open the submenu is also not triggered.

To me it looks like some parts are not compiled although I compile the whole foundation framework, not only specific modules.

Has anybody an idea where I can start searching? The other parts of the menu work great.

Here´s the HTML code:

```
<aside class="left-off-canvas-menu" aria-hidden="true">
            <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                <li><label>Navigationsmenü</label></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Mein Warenkorb</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Zur Kasse</a></li>
                <li><label>Mein Konto</label></li>
                <li class="my-account">
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <img src="<?php echo "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( 'mail@mail.com' ) ) ) . "?s=100";?>" class="avatar" alt="Avatar" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="user">
                        <span class="title">John Doe</span>
                        <span class="email">email@email.com</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="mtm button primary tiny"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Meine Daten ändern</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Adressbuch bearbeiten</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Meine Bestellungen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Passwort ändern</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;E-Mail Adresse ändern</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ausloggen</a></li>
                <li><label>Produktkategorien</label></li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Aktionen</a>
                    <ul class="left-submenu">
                        <li class="back"><a href="#">Zurück</a></li>
                        <li><label>Level 1</label></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sonderangebote der Woche</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Monatsaktionen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Spezialaktionen</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Maximal sparen</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Gutscheine</a></li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Ernährung</a>
                    <ul class="left-submenu">
                        <li class="back"><a href="#">Zurück</a></li>
                        <li><label>Level 1</label></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nahrungsergänzungsmittel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vitamine & Mineralstoffe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Spezialnahrung</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Gesund abnehmen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sportlernahrung</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
```

And that´s the SCSS file (app.scss):

```
@import "compass/css3/border-radius";
@import "compass/css3/box-shadow";

@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
```

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Need to see some code before we can help

Comment: I´ve added some code snippets to my question.

Comment: Ok - Core foundation is not going to work like this without adding some custom javascript to open and close those sub-menus within the off-canvas menu

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/20747-off-canvas-menu-with-slide-down-submenus here is a forum post that can point you in the right direction